# clear session variable after refreshing PHPpage

Tags: php

I have a page where i have set countdown timer. After the login of user, the count down starts ticking, but when i refresh the page countdown doesn't restart instead it continues with the previous time. i want this timer to restart every time i refresh the page.

am trying this

```
  <?php
    session_start();
     if(!isset($_SESSION['starttime'])){
     unset($_SESSION['starttime']);
     }
      else if (!isset($_SESSION['starttime']) && isset($_SESSION['start']))       
          {

    $_SESSION['starttime'] = time();
       } 
     ?>
```

this is timer..

```
    <?php
    if ( isset($_SESSION['starttime'])) {
    $elapsed = (time() - $_SESSION['starttime']);
   // $elasped = (time () - $starttime);
    if (($elapsed / 60) < 2) {
        echo "var hour=00;";
        if ($elapsed == 0)
            $elapsed = 1;
        echo "min=" . (int) (5 - ($elapsed / 60)) . ";";
        if ($elapsed > 60)
            echo "sec=" . (60 - ($elapsed - 60)) . ";";
        else
            echo "sec=" . (60 - $elapsed) . ";";
    }
    else {
        echo "var hour=0;var min=0;sec=01;";
        unset($_SESSION['starttime'])
        header('location:index.php');
                exit();
    }
}
?>
```

am stuck here.

Comment: don't you think you should validate with if(isset($_SESSION['starttime'])) instead of if(!isset($_SESSION['starttime'])) ?

Comment: I also think the same @KhanShahrukh. Whole Bollywood Here In Stack Overflow. Achha Hain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The isset() function return false if testing variable contains a NULL
>   value.

Change in if condition.

```
     <?php
     session_start();
     if(isset($_SESSION['starttime'])){ // Change here.
        unset($_SESSION['starttime']);
     }
     else if (!isset($_SESSION['starttime']) && isset($_SESSION['start']))       
     {
        $_SESSION['starttime'] = time();
     }?>
```

Comment: Nana Party kar lol thats funny ! get in touch ? my email is in my profile

Comment: Yeah Sure @KhanShahrukh. I will be in touch. I Will mail you tonight. Thanks.

Comment: If you think, my answer helped you. You can tick it as correct answer. As it will help other users to find answer easily. @SagarPawar

Comment: ya bro am trying to tick but its telling me to wait for 1 min..;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `!` before `isset($_SESSION['starttime'])`. [`isset()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['starttime'])){ // Change Here
        unset($_SESSION['starttime']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `!` from `if(!isset($_SESSION['starttime'])){`

And the below code should be like this, there is no need of checking not isset in second condition as well because it came to second condition when 1st is not correct.

```
<?php
    session_start();
     if(isset($_SESSION['starttime'])){
        unset($_SESSION['starttime']);
     }else if (isset($_SESSION['start'])){
        $_SESSION['starttime'] = time();
     } 
?>
```